# Google Analytics event tracking - max string length

Tags: android, string, events, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics for tracking events in my Android App. My question is: is there a limit for the string length in an event? I have found nothing about this topic on Googles devguide site.

Best regards!

**Edit:**
I tried it whith a string with 2000 characters - and it works. If you need more (I don't believe), than try it first.

Comment: Confirmed. 2070 is too much, 1997 is okay.

Comment: How is it possible to have 2000 character if the limit is 500 bytes.  I thought 1 character = 1 byte?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

According to the official documentation,

- Max Length for [**Event Category**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ec) = 150 Bytes
- Max Length for [**Event Action**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ea) = 500 Bytes
- Max Length for [**Event Label**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#el) = 500 Bytes
- For all other parameters, you can check in [the same page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters).

Long text is automatically truncated according to [this doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference#maxlength):

> If any of the values are greater than the maximum lengths, they will automatically be truncated. If a multi-byte character exceeds the maximum length, the entire character will be truncated.

Answer (score 3):

@Pang's answer is correct for Universal Analytics (UA). But the latest version of Google Analytics isn't UA, it's Google Analytics 4 (GA4), and [GA4 has different limits](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267744?hl=en):

| Logged item | Limit |
| --- | --- |
| Distinctly named events | 500 per app instance (app) Automatically collected events, like first_open and in_app_purchase, and events you collect via enhanced measurement do not count toward the limits. |
| Length of event name | 40 characters |
| Event parameters per event | 25 event parameters |
| Length of event-parameter name | 40 characters |
| Length of event-parameter value | 100 characters |
| User properties | 25 per property |
| Length of user-property names | 24 characters |
| Length of user-property values | 36 characters |
| Length of User-ID values | 256 characters |

Answer (score 0):

Note that Google Analytics will give a 414 error and tell you that your string is too long, when in fact you've sent a malformed string. Just take a modest string and insert a few spaces to see for yourself.

Answer (score -4):

The maximum event label string length is 2048 bytes: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference#maxlength

Comment: This is incorrect. The link in the reply refers to the document referrer field, dr. Please check out https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#events instead. 500 B seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: 2048 bytes is the maximum legth for the hit payload. The maximum string length depends on the field (see @Pang's answer).